# React | NextJS : Cannot use props returned by getInitialProps()

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying SSR with NextJS for the first time and I am unable to access the props returned from the getInitialProps():

> Error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

> index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Index = ({ posts }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Our Index Page!</h1>
            <ul>
                {posts.map(post => (
                    <li key={post.id}>post.title</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
Index.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
    const url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    const res = await axios.get(url);
    const { data } = res;
    return { posts: data } // this returns data as posts in the props to the component
};

export default Index;
```

> In case you want to check the **_app.js**:

```
import React from 'react'
import App from 'next/app'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';

class MyApp extends App {
    static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
        let pageProps = {};

        if (Component.getInitialProps) {
            pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
        }

        return { pageProps };
    }
    render() {
        const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar />
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MyApp;
```

Pretty sure I am missing something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching

Comment: this looks ok to me; i created a sandbox here with your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-clarke-m47ti?file=/pages/index.js ..and it works fine?

Answer (score 0):

In my setup it is working well, I was only able simulate type null pointer error by eg. not waiting for response from axios, pls. check following:

- axios past bug: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1086
- npm update axios
- try rewrite code to ensure data are sent OK, log: status, conf, headers, data - eventually catch exception

```
       return await axios.get(url).then((res) => {console.log(res.status);
          console.log(res.config);
          console.log(res.headers);
          console.log(res.data);
          return { posts: res.data }
        }).catch((e) => {
          console.log('error: ', e)
        })
```